# Is standard deviation always larger than mean deviation?

Tags: standard-deviation, dispersion, mean-absolute-deviation

If yes why is it the case that it have this property? There must be some mathematical proof or intuitive understanding in that case.

Comment: How do you define mean deviation?

Comment: There is a proof on the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation

Comment: The duplicate concerns a generalization: the mean deviation corresponds to $n=1$ while the SD corresponds to $n=2$.